# Calculate Column Sum of a Generated Table - DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I've been trying to get the sum of the following table's column **VALUE** using **DaxStudio** in order to put that on PowerBI once is's ok, since PBI can get slow if you test a code for large calculated tables.

### Table from DaxStudio

```
   BU              VALUE    
   ------------------------
   FOODS            0.0000
   FIBI             0.0000
   GEOS/CIS         0.7300
   CASC 
   S_S  
   SGS  
   COCOA    
   COCOA/SSSA   
   CORPORATE    
   N/A  
   CIS
```

### The code behind it:

```
DEFINE
    VAR TOTAL =
        CALCULATE (
            SUMX (
                PACKAGING_POWERBI_YEARLY_2;
                PACKAGING_POWERBI_YEARLY_2[QUANTIDADE_ANTERIOR]
            );
            FILTER (
                PACKAGING_POWERBI_YEARLY_2;
                PACKAGING_POWERBI_YEARLY_2[DATE] = "2018"
                    && PACKAGING_POWERBI_YEARLY_2[CODIGO] = "43130"
            )
        )
EVALUATE
SUMMARIZE (
    CALCULATETABLE (
        FILTER (
            PACKAGING_POWERBI_YEARLY_2;
            PACKAGING_POWERBI_YEARLY_2[PRECO_PONDERADO] <> BLANK ()
                && PACKAGING_POWERBI_YEARLY_2[PRECO_PONDERADO] <> 0
        )
    );
    PACKAGING_POWERBI_YEARLY_2[BU];
    "VALUE"; FORMAT (
        (
            CALCULATE (
                SUMX (
                    PACKAGING_POWERBI_YEARLY_2;
                    PACKAGING_POWERBI_YEARLY_2[QUANTIDADE_ANTERIOR]
                );
                FILTER (
                    PACKAGING_POWERBI_YEARLY_2;
                    PACKAGING_POWERBI_YEARLY_2[DATE] = "2018"
                        && PACKAGING_POWERBI_YEARLY_2[CODIGO] = "43130"
                        && PACKAGING_POWERBI_YEARLY_2[PRECO_PONDERADO] <> BLANK ()
                )
            ) / TOTAL
        )
            * (
                CALCULATE (
                    SUMX ( PACKAGING_POWERBI_YEARLY_2; PACKAGING_POWERBI_YEARLY_2[PRECO_PONDERADO] );
                    FILTER (
                        PACKAGING_POWERBI_YEARLY_2;
                        PACKAGING_POWERBI_YEARLY_2[DATE] = "2018"
                            && PACKAGING_POWERBI_YEARLY_2[CODIGO] = "43130"
                            && PACKAGING_POWERBI_YEARLY_2[PRECO_PONDERADO] <> BLANK ()
                    )
                )
            );
        "0.0000"
    )
)
```

Instead of generating the table I would like to sum the results of column **VALUE**, but the only way I got to plot a result without error is through a "CALCULATED TABLE" (above).

Every filter I try leads to an error.

The idea is to get just the sum of that calculated column **VALUE**:

```
   0.7300
```

But every simpler filter or **SUMX** condition I try, an error pops-up.

Answer (score 2):

I'd think you could clean it up to look something like this:

```
CALCULATE (
    SUMX (
        VALUES ( PACKAGING_POWERBI_YEARLY_2[BU] ),
        SUM ( PACKAGING_POWERBI_YEARLY_2[QUANTIDADE_ANTERIOR] )
            / CALCULATE (
                SUM ( PACKAGING_POWERBI_YEARLY_2[QUANTIDADE_ANTERIOR] ),
                ALL ( PACKAGING_POWERBI_YEARLY_2[BU] )
            )
            * SUM ( PACKAGING_POWERBI_YEARLY_2[PRECO_PONDERADO] )
    ),
    FILTER (
        PACKAGING_POWERBI_YEARLY_2,
        PACKAGING_POWERBI_YEARLY_2[DATE] = "2018"
            && PACKAGING_POWERBI_YEARLY_2[CODIGO] = "43130"
            && PACKAGING_POWERBI_YEARLY_2[PRECO_PONDERADO] <> BLANK ()
            && PACKAGING_POWERBI_YEARLY_2[PRECO_PONDERADO] <> 0
    )
)
```

This uses `SUMX` to iterate through each of the `BU` values and for each one, calculates the value

```
(QUANTIDADE_ANTERIOR / Total QUANTIDADE_ANTERIOR ) * PRECO_PONDERADO
```

where the filters are reused instead of repeated.

---

I can't guarantee that this code works exactly as intended, but it should point you in a better direction.

Comment: Although it's retrieving some error, it helps to the correct path I think. I am breaking down the calculation you shared and figuring out the proper adjustment. I'll post here the final code as soon I get it running...Than you very much!